# Removing Windows PowerToys' Mouse Highlighter artifacts from screen

Tags: windows, mouse, highlighting

*This is a question and answer pair for a problem I've endured for a couple of weeks and couldn't find an answer on the web.*

PowerToys v0.78.0

Microsoft's [PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/mouse-utilities) has a useful Mouse Highlighter utility that I am using for some software demonstrations. The highlighted cursor looks as shown in (1) below but intermittently a left click (with a red highlight) leaves an artifact on the screen.

[image]

*Figure 1. (1) The cursor highlight is yellow in my configuration. (The crosshairs are black but didn't come out in the screengrab.) (2) and (3) the artifacts left by a left-click (red in my config).*

I've tried all the suggested tricks to clear them - lock screen which clears the artifacts until you log back in again; change screen resolution which didn't work; etc. I'm having to reboot when the artifacts get in the way of my demonstrations.

Is there a solution?
Can anyone explain on what "layer" the artifacts might be hiding and why none of the tricks clear them?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Mouse Highlighter has a hotkey combination Win-Shift-H to toggle the highlighter on and off. It turns out that the hotkey clears the artifacts! (I've only done it once and it may be some days before they show up again.)

I'd still like to understand where in the hardware or software they reside and why a screen refresh or similar can't clear them.